# Blender animation in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, 3d, blender

Hi I have my stickman with bones etc in blender. I want to use him in my WPF/C# application to make some simple app like shaking hand or move leg. I found some graphic engines but they cost a lot, is there any free solution to import stickman from blender and make some simple animation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Unity](http://unity3d.com/).

A quick search reveals you can import files from Blender to it: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/HOWTO-ImportObjectBlender.html

Comment: If i want to use unity 3d engine in my app I need to pay 1500$.

Comment: As long as your company doesn't turn over more than $100,000USD then you can use the free version. http://unity3d.com/unity/licenses

Answer (score 2):

There are a few options I know of you could look at

[HowTo Create 3D Blender Model for use in WPF](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NWLSIC1Q4gU) 
[Blender and XNA Animations](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SissgQ0IXvk)
[Unity](http://unity3d.com/)

Comment: I already tried export to xaml, its working fine with simple cube, but if yuor object its bigger it will generate so many code that my VS just stack when trying to run program. Unity is not free engine it cost 1500$ to use it in yuor own app, I dont try XNA yet I'll try that.

Answer (score -1):

These are different products provided by different vendors:

blender: for animation creation, game, etc, replacing 3D maya studio;

blend: supplied with microsoft visual studio, to write xaml wpf;

unity: an ide for game spicifically.

Comment: You are not even correct with your definitions. Blender is a free and open-source 3D computer graphics software tool set used for creating animated films, visual effects, art, 3D-printed models, motion graphics, interactive 3D applications, virtual reality, and, formerly, video games. Unity is a cross-platform game engine developed by Unity Technologies. Nobody asked about Microsoft Blend...