# WPF C# AB3d animation

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I need to do a 3d project in WPF in my school, I wanted to do a very complex animation. So I checked out the ab3d software, where you can export animation to 3ds file and convert them. But I try again and again to export 3ds file from blender with animation, I keyframed it, and it doesn't work. but their example files are working, and when I import them to blender, no animation exits.
Can someone help me understand how I export 3d animation to 3ds file?
here are some pics for with animation and without.
links to the files: [Without](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vDD3f5V5BpARGu_6mjYOfDUhH80lvyzN) [With](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1q8QfZgj7jipn_b2S__ZIEFYFpXQI3fE-)
(I want to mention that when I import the file back to blender, no animation)
without:
[image: blender animtion]
[image: ab3d no animation]
with:
[image: with]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blender animation in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21578549/blender-animation-in-wpf)

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica 
No. but thanks for trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know a long time has passed but I had figured it out.
It appears to be that blender 3ds exporter for some reason can't export animation in 3ds format.
Therefore to solve it you need to transfer your model to other programs, like [3ds](https://www.autodesk.com/products/3ds-max/overview),
and only their animate, then export your model as a 3ds file.
Works like a charm:)